# Disable extract from archive

Tags: encryption, archiving, extract

I want to compress a file with encryption;  but would also like to prevent extraction/saving of the file from archive.  In other words,  user can only print the file.

This is for added security.  Does any tool allow this ?

Comment: No. If the OS can read the file, it can save the file.

Comment: I think Adobe/PDF has a feature to disable save of a file.

Comment: You cannot open a file without it being on a disk, so it is saved, and if it is on a disk it can be copied, independently of Adobe products.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible, because in order to print the file it must be extracted from the archive, and then any limintations regarding how the file can be used are reliant on the currently used OS's permissions for that file.

You could always avoid giving the users the password for the archive, and instead give them a bat script that extracts it to a hidden temp directory, prints it, and then deletes the extracted version. Of course users with any tech knowlegde will simply extract the password from the bat script by opening it in notepad.